# Fetch the missing package.xml in an open source unmanaged package

Tags: package, package-install, unmanaged-package, package.xml

I found this [open source repo](https://github.com/CopadoSolutions/ccm-integration), and want to fork from it for own usage.

Then I realize that the `package.xml` is not present in the repo. It is excluded by `.gitignore` for whatever reason.

I perceive that I need it as part of my forked repo to allow to install into Salesforce orgs.

The package installing URL is [here](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1r000000b6f5) for prod/dev org. I wonder if AppExchange allows me to see the xml file, but somehow I couldn't find the correct way to nail the app in AppExchange.

What shall I do?

Comment: Based on the metadata which you would like to deploy, you can prepare your own sample `package.xml`. you can use `*` in members to deploy all components for a type. Example for custom object would be as `<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>`

Comment: thanks for commeting. This was also the way I considered. It seems sfdcfox has a better/quick way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the package, you can then retrieve it from the org via SFDX:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -p "CCM Integrations" -r . -s -w 10
```

Or, alternatively, whichever IDE you use should have similar functionality, such as Force.com IDE.

Whichever way you retrieve it, you'll get the package.xml you're looking for. I'd probably consider raising an issue on the repo to include either a DX-compatible format or a package.xml file. Without either, you're left with manually creating it or installing it and picking out the file you need back from the server.

Comment: thx! This is a nice way. I did create an issue in the repo. Another related question, why can't I nail this package in AppExchange from the installing URL?

Comment: @XiXiao not sure I understand the question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: In the question, I have linked the installing URL: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1r000000b6f5 which I assume it redirects the browser to AppExchange, fetch and install. Is it possible to locate this app in AppExchange according to the info from this URL? I have tried with app name and the id, no success.

Comment: @XiXiao No, there's no way to find out. The installation link is separate from the AppExchange listing, and in fact, there may not be a listing at all for most links you'll encounter outside the AppExchange.